# Issue while resolving hostname

Tags: python, networking, centos, hostname, resolve

I have the following code,

```
import urllib2
for i in range(0,100):
    expanded_url = urllib2.urlopen('http://4sq.com/1iyfyI5')
    print expanded_url.url
```

This code is able to resolve the url for say 4-5 times in centos machine, then it fails with the following error each time when rerun is done:

```
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>
```

When I run in different centos machine, it is able to resolve without any error all 100 times. I think there will not be any issue in network side, as it is working fine in another machine(both machines are in same network and have centos 6.5). Any way to debug this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable debugging to see what's happening:

```
handler = urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=1)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(handler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
expanded_url = urllib2.urlopen('http://4sq.com/1iyfyI5')
print expanded_url.url
```